# How to query variable from database using php

Tags: php, html, database

Good Day developers outthere! 
I just wanna ask what is the problem with my code, I'm trying to make a webpage using html,css,php and database. Now I already created a php in my html form and my database is already connected, but everytime I submit the information in the html form I created, nothing appeared in my database.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['save'])){ 
    $FName = $_POST['FName'];
    $MName = $_POST['MName']; 
    echo "Successfully Added";
    $sql= "INSERT INTO 'tbstudinfo' (Transaction_Number, First_Name, `Middle_Name') VALUES ('000',$FName,$MName)";
} else{ 
    echo "<p>Insertion Failed.</p>"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: And the code is ?

Comment: Already posted sir sorry for rush post I forgot to add my code.

Comment: Please post your code as text. You need to execute your query

Comment: This is my php file sir.
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        $FName = $_POST['FName'];
        $MName = $_POST['MName'];
        echo "Successfully Added";

         $sql= "INSERT INTO 'tbstudinfo' (`Transaction_Number`, `First_Name`, `Middle_Name')
            VALUES ('000',$FName,$MName)";
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed.</p>";
}
?>

Comment: <input class="input--style-1" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FName">     
                            <input class="input--style-1" type="text" placeholder="Middle Name" name="MName">
                            <input class="input--style-1" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="LName">

Comment: How do you connect to Database ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion  this is my second time to post in this website

Comment: I wrote file named connect.php by using this code.
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "dbthesis";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

Comment: and then I include the connection in my html and php file like this.
 <?php
    include_once 'connect.php';
    ?>

Comment: Edit your question to add the extra information. Do not put it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @executable mentioned, you are defining query in your code but not executing it.

1. Define Connection Object (Mysqli, PDO..)
2. Prepare Query and Bind Variables
3. Execute your query

Here's an example using prepared statements

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if( isset($_POST['save']) ){
    // prepare and bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO 'tbstudinfo' (Transaction_Number, First_Name, Middle_Name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $transaction_number, $FName, $MName);

    // set parameters and execute
    $transaction_number = '000';
    $FName= $_POST['FName'];
    $MName= $_POST['MName'];
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Successfully Added";

}else{
    echo "<p>Nothing Posted</p>";
}
```

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) and [PHP.Net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) both have pretty good examples about how to use prepared statements to make your SQL Query more secure from [SQL Injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You simply don't execute your query. Using MySQLi :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "dbthesis"; 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db); 

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if(isset($_POST['save'])){ 
    $FName = $_POST['FName'];
    $MName = $_POST['MName']; 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbstudinfo (Transaction_Number, First_Name, Middle_Name) VALUES ('000', '$FName', '$MName')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Successfully Added";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Insertion Failed.</p>"; 
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around `$FName` and `$MName` inside the query.

Answer (score 0):

You only making a query, not running query. This this code

```
$FName = $_POST['FName'];
$MName = $_POST['MName'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbstudioinfo (Transaction_Number, First_Name, Middle_Name) VALUES ('000','$FName','$MName')";

// code below runs your query

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Successfully Added";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```